# What would be the advantages of taking a Software Project Management course for Data Scientists?

Tags: career, education

What would be the advantages of a Software Project Management course for a data scientist, from both an entrepreneurial and a job-seeking point of view.  How beneficial this course would be compared to just read/take online courses?

**TL;DR version:**
I am a Master Student in Data Science (my bachelors was on Computer Science) and one week ago I was offered to take a limited course on Software Project Management.  In this course, I would act **either** as a project manager or quality assurance manager for a group of Bachelor students doing their SEP project. My activities would include:

Project manager / scrum master

- Planning: chairs planning sessions, stand up meetings, demos and retrospectives
- Organizes scrum board, keeps back log up to date
- Reports progress to senior management:
          Weekly progress sessions
          Weekly e-mail metrics (time tracking)

Quality engineer / manager

- Checks quality of documents
- Takes care that reviews are held
- Takes care that a proper testing environment is set up by the group
- Enforces “continuous testing”  approach
- Organizes peer reviews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In agile we like to stress you are never "done". The best teams are always continuing to learn and improve. Like a world champion sports team, the best agile teams and individuals never take a season off.

If you're getting a chance to learn more, then take it. Odds are incredibly high it will have some use/bearing on your future job and skills.

One small note- Scrum Master and Project Manager are two very different jobs. I've done both. Project Manager is the "chief traffic cop". Scrum Master is chief "cook and bottle washer". A PM's job is to call account and make sure the project is one schedule. An SM's job is to enable the team however they can to make them successful.

Be a Scrum Master, not a Project Manager. Today's software industry needs PMs and SMs that think like SMs, not like legacy PMs.

Coming from a former Command and Control Project Manager turned Scrum Master turned Agile Coach.

Best of luck and enjoy the class!

Comment: This information was quite useful. Thanks a lot @joel.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you were offered to take the course for free ?
If free , i would take any one of the courses depending on your future goals.

If you want to be in testing , take the QA course.

if you want to be in management. take the Project management course. But this would be far off as you first need to learn the bolts and nuts of development before you delve into this.

If you want to familiarize yourself with Agile , take the Scrum Master course ( This is the one i will lean towards if i was a masters student and nearing a job in near future )

if project management/scrum master are bunched together go for that one.